# Divide polygon segments equally

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the triangle shape below, what would be the right way to divide the edges of the triangle equally instead of specifying absolute coordinates. Goal is to place a horizontal line between the two parallel edges on either sides and likewise equally spaced vertical lines between the base edges. In between place  a text and a text above and below, or to the left and right as the case may be.

For example, I'd like to divide the edges by four equally spaced horizontal bars, place a text above it and on either side - i.e. one inside the inner triangle and one outside the outer triangle.
[image]

see code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=1.5]
\draw (8.,0.) -- (14.,0.) -- (11.,5.196152422706633) -- cycle;
\draw (9.,0.5) -- (13.,0.5) -- (11.,4.196152422706633) -- cycle;
\draw (8.,0.) -- (9., 0.5);
\draw (14.,0.) -- (13., 0.5);
\draw (11.,5.196152422706633) -- (11.,4.196152422706633);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use polar coordinates for the triangles, and some auxiliary coordinates together with the `calc` library to place the texts. I defined a command `\DivideSide` allowing you to specify the number of subdivisions for each side; this command allocates also some coordinates to allow placement of texts in each of the subdivisions:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\DivideSide[4]{
\foreach \Value [evaluate=\Value as \Parts using \Value/#1] in {1,...,\numexpr#1-1\relax}
\draw
  ( $ (#22)!\Parts!(#32) $ ) -- coordinate (#4\Value) 
    ( $ (#21)!($(#22)!\Parts!(#32)$)!(#31) $ );
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw 
(8,0) coordinate (left1) -- ++(0:6) coordinate (right1) -- ++(120:6) coordinate (top1) -- cycle
(9.,0.5) coordinate (left2) -- ++(0:4) coordinate (right2) -- ++(120:4) coordinate (top2) -- cycle
(8,0) -- coordinate (MiddleLeft) (9,0.5)
(14,0) -- coordinate (MiddleRight) (13,0.5)
(top1) -- coordinate (MiddleTop) (top2);

% Subdivide the sides
\DivideSide{3}{left}{top}{LeftSide}
\DivideSide{4}{right}{top}{RightSide}
\DivideSide{5}{right}{left}{BottomSide}

% Labels for the left side
\node[rotate=60] at
  ( $ (MiddleLeft)!0.5!(LeftSide1) $ )
  {a};  
\node[rotate=60] at
  ( $ (LeftSide1)!0.5!(LeftSide2) $ )
  {b};  
\node[rotate=60] at
  ( $ (LeftSide2)!0.5!(MiddleTop) $ )
  {c};  

% Labels for the right side
\node[rotate=-60] at
  ( $ (MiddleTop)!0.5!(RightSide3) $ )
  {d};  
\node[rotate=-60] at
  ( $ (RightSide3)!0.5!(RightSide2) $ )
  {e};  
\node[rotate=-60] at
  ( $ (RightSide2)!0.5!(RightSide1) $ )
  {f};  
\node[rotate=-60] at
  ( $ (RightSide1)!0.5!(MiddleRight) $ )
  {g};  

% Labels for the bottom side
\node at
  ( $ (MiddleRight)!0.5!(BottomSide1) $ )
  {h};  
\node at
  ( $ (BottomSide1)!0.5!(BottomSide2) $ )
  {i};  
\node at
  ( $ (BottomSide2)!0.5!(BottomSide3) $ )
  {j};  
\node at
  ( $ (BottomSide3)!0.5!(BottomSide4) $ )
  {k};  
\node at
  ( $ (BottomSide4)!0.5!(MiddleLeft) $ )
  {l};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see my comment above

Comment: @jayr Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried using same principles to generate a square. Did not work. Where's the mistake? I updated my question with example

Comment: @jayr Please don't do that. This deserves a completely new question as a follow-uo to this one. I'd suggest you to roll-back your edit and open a fresh new question with this new problem.

Comment: updated. did not know policy.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Gonzalo Medina answer, I try to write shorter code. As Gonzalo's solution it use `calc` TikZ library, main difference is, how are positioned nodes with text in triangle's parts. For text I also stool Gonzales's nomenclature.

Since I do not figured out, why the starting coordinates in question's MWE is `(8,0)`. I change it to `(0,0)`.

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm,
                   tikz,
                   preview]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
        \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=1.5]
\draw   (0,0.0) coordinate (a)  -- ++ 
        (6,0.0) coordinate (b)  -- ++ 
        (120:6) coordinate (c)  -- cycle;
\draw   (1,0.5) coordinate (a') -- ++ 
        (4,0.0) coordinate (b') -- ++ 
        (120:4) coordinate (c')  -- cycle;;
\draw (a) -- (a')   (b) -- (b') (c) -- (c');
%
\draw   ($(a)!0.5!(b)$) coordinate (mb) -- ++ (0,0.5);
\draw   ($(b')!0.5!(c')$) coordinate (mr) -- ($(b)!0.5!(c)$);
\draw   ($(a')!0.5!(c')$) coordinate (ml) -- ($(a)!0.5!(c)$);
%
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={inner ysep=3mm,text depth=0.3 ex}]
\path   (a') -- node {bottom left} (mb) -- node {bottom right} (b');
\path   (a') -- node[above,sloped] {left lower} (ml) 
             -- node[above,sloped] {left upper} (c');
\path   (b') -- node[above,sloped] {right lower} (mr)
             -- node[above,sloped] {right upper} (c');
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Image, produced with above code is:

[image]

**Edit:**
For dividing borders into more then two parts you need considered borders fraction of outer triangle are not perpendicular on the same fraction off inner. So you need consider to use different approach: drawing perpendicular lines between borders. In this should be considered that inner triangle is not only scaled version of outside one, but is also shifted down. Consequently, distance between them are different at bottom (5 mm) and on upper left and right side (~6,1604 mm). So you need to use some geometry to fix this.

Firs let calculate distance between upper left and right side of triangles. From geometry follows, that it is:

```
(10 - 5/tan(60))cos(30) [mm]
```

Knowing dis distance, the lines between parts of border can be drawn with

```
\draw   ($(b')!0.33!(c')$) coordinate (mr1) -- ($(mr1)!6.16mm!90:(b')$);
```

(for upper right border). It position is determined with term in the first bracket.  This approach can be used ill three border, or for bottom one use some simplification, because there are lines orthogonal.

With considering aforementioned the code is:

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm,
                   tikz,
                   many,
                   preview]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
        \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=1.5]
\draw   (0,0.0) coordinate (a)  -- ++
        (6,0.0) coordinate (b)  -- ++
        (120:6) coordinate (c)  -- cycle;
\draw   (1,0.5) coordinate (a') -- ++
        (4,0.0) coordinate (b') -- ++
        (120:4) coordinate (c')  -- cycle;;
\draw (a) -- (a')   (b) -- (b') (c) -- (c');
% in case of more than 2 parts in lower border
\draw   ($(a)!0.33!(b)$) coordinate (mb1) -- ++ (0,0.5);
\draw   ($(a)!0.66!(b)$) coordinate (mb2) -- ++ (0,0.5);
% in case of more than 2 parts in upper right border
% distance 6.16 = (10 - 5/tan(60))cos(30) in [mm]
\draw   ($(b')!0.33!(c')$) coordinate (mr1) -- ($(mr1)!6.16mm!90:(b')$);
\draw   ($(b')!0.66!(c')$) coordinate (mr2) -- ($(mr2)!6.16mm!90:(b')$);
%
\draw   ($(a')!0.5!(c')$) coordinate (ml) -- ($(a)!0.5!(c)$);
%
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={inner ysep=3mm,text depth=0.3 ex}]
\path   (a') -- node {A} (mb1) 
             ++ (0,0.5) % for going on opposite side of line, 
                        % necessary fo
             -- node {B} (mb2)
             -- node {C} (b');
\path   (a') -- node[above,sloped] {left lower} (ml)
             -- node[above,sloped] {left upper} (c');
\path   (b') -- node[above,sloped] {D} (mr1) 
             -- node[above,sloped] {E} (mr2) 
             -- node[above,sloped] {F} (c');
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

So, lines dividing border parts are parallel!

Comment: The small shortcoming is, say to divide the segments in more fractions, like 3 or 5 or 10, as in: `\draw ($(b')!0.25!(c')$) coordinate (mr) -- ($(b)!0.25!(c)$);` the lines are not parallel. It would need some trigonometric correction since the two edges are of different length?

Comment: @jayr, regarding trigonometric correction, you have right. However, they are relatively simple. See upgrade of my answer.

Comment: how can those divisions be driven by parameters so that absolute numbers such as $0.33$ or $6.16$ be expressed as math functions?

Comment: @jayr, good question. To receive more suggestion, how to do this, I suggest you to ask it as new question. Points of dividing triangle border can be determined on many different ways, one is determine distance from one of triangle corner, where distance you measure with `\setowidth` and of save box, in which you save text which you like to put in border. this length you also can divided with triangle side length and this value use in  `\draw ($(b')!\mylength!(c')$) ` (not tested).