# Divide rectangle segments equally

Tags: tikz-pgf

@Gonzalo Medina offered a solution in [Divide polygon segments equally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269984/divide-polygon-segments-equally)

Tried the same principle with a square. Did not work. See code below. Are `MiddleLeft` `BottomSide` etc. keywords in tikz?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=1.5]

\draw   (0,0) coordinate (a)  --  
        (6,0) coordinate (b)  --  
        (6,6.0) coordinate (c)  --  
        (0,6) coordinate (d)  -- cycle;

\draw   (1.0,1.0) coordinate (a')  --  
    (5,1.0) coordinate (b')  --  
    (5,5) coordinate (c')  -- 
    (1.0,5) coordinate (d')  -- cycle;

\draw (a) -- (a')   (b) -- (b') (c) -- (c') (d) -- (d');

(a) -- coordinate (MiddleLeft) (a')
(b) -- coordinate (MiddleRight) (b')
\DivideSide{5}{right}{left}{BottomSide}
% Labels for the bottom side
\node at
  ( $ (MiddleRight)!0.5!(BottomSide1) $ )
  {h};  
\node at
  ( $ (BottomSide1)!0.5!(BottomSide2) $ )
  {i};  
\node at
  ( $ (BottomSide2)!0.5!(BottomSide3) $ )
  {j};  
\node at
  ( $ (BottomSide3)!0.5!(BottomSide4) $ )
  {k};  
\node at
  ( $ (BottomSide4)!0.5!(MiddleLeft) $ )
  {l};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: No they simply are names I chose.

Comment: how to interpret  `(a) -- coordinate (MiddleLeft) (a')` and  `\node at
  ( $ (MiddleRight)!0.5!(BottomSide1) $ )
  {h};  `

Comment: This `(a) -- coordinate (MiddleLeft) (a')` places a coordinate called `MiddleLeft` in the midpoint between `(a)` and `(a')`. This `\node at ( $ (MiddleRight)!0.5!(BottomSide1) $ ) {h};`  places a node with text `h` at the midpoint between `(MiddleRight)` and `(BottomSide1)`.

Comment: I think I am going to use a completely new approach here. Do you need this procedure to apply to regular polygons (triangles, squares, pentagons, etc?)

Comment: Triangles and Squares are enough. The only other option is to be able to place text not just inside the lines, need text placed optionally inside the triangle or some times outside the triangle/square sides, corresponding to the `y` location or `x` of the inside text (depending on horizontal/vertical). In case of triangle text can fall on imaginary line perpendicular to edge, one in the inner triangle, one inside, one outside. All text should be readable without rotating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100cm,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
  myshape/.style 2 args={
    inner sep=0pt,
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=#1,
    minimum size=#2
  }
}

\newcommand\DrawShape[3]{
  \node[draw,myshape={#1}{#2}] (inner) {};
  \node[draw,myshape={#1}{#3}] (outer) {};
  \node[myshape={#1}{0.5*#3+0.5*#2}] (in) {};
  \node[myshape={#1}{#3+40pt}] (outside) {};
  \node[myshape={#1}{#2-40pt}] (inside) {};
  \foreach \Value in {1,...,#1}
  {
    \draw  (inner.corner \Value) -- (outer.corner \Value);
  }  
}

\newcommand\LabelsIn[3]{
  \foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {}
  \foreach \Value [count=\Num,evaluate=\Value as \Parts using \Value/\Total] in {1,...,\numexpr\Total-1\relax}
  {
    \draw 
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- 
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
  }
  \foreach \Text [count=\Num,evaluate=\Text as \Parts using (\Num/\Total)-1/(2*\Total)] in {#1} 
  {
    \path[]
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- node {\Text}
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
  }
}

\newcommand\LabelsInside[3]{
  \foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {}
  \foreach \Text [count=\Num,evaluate=\Text as \Parts using (\Num/\Total)-1/(2*\Total)] in {#1} 
  {
    \path[]
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- node[pos=-0.4] {\Text}
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
  }
}

\newcommand\LabelsOutside[3]{
  \foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {}
  \foreach \Text [count=\Num,evaluate=\Text as \Parts using (\Num/\Total)-1/(2*\Total)] in {#1} 
  {
    \path[]
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- node[pos=1.4] {\Text}
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawShape{3}{7cm}{10cm}
\LabelsIn{1,2,3,4}{1}{2}
\LabelsInside{A,B,C,D}{1}{2}
\LabelsOutside{a,b,c,d}{1}{2}
\LabelsIn{5,6}{2}{3}
\LabelsInside{E,F}{2}{3}
\LabelsOutside{e,f}{2}{3}
\LabelsIn{7,8,9}{3}{1}
\LabelsInside{G,H,I}{3}{1}
\LabelsOutside{g,h,i}{3}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawShape{4}{8cm}{12cm}
\LabelsIn{A,B,C}{1}{2}
\LabelsInside{1,2,3}{1}{2}
\LabelsOutside{a,b,c}{1}{2}
\LabelsIn{D,E}{2}{3}
\LabelsInside{4,5}{2}{3}
\LabelsOutside{d,e}{2}{3}
\LabelsIn{F,G}{3}{4}
\LabelsInside{6,7}{3}{4}
\LabelsOutside{f,g}{3}{4}
\LabelsIn{H,I,J,K,L}{4}{1}
\LabelsInside{8,9,10,11,\raisebox{-30pt}{12}}{4}{1}
\LabelsOutside{h,i,j,k,l}{4}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawShape{5}{8cm}{12cm}
\LabelsIn{7,8,9}{1}{2}
\LabelsIn{e,f,g,h,i}{2}{3}
\LabelsIn{p,q,r}{3}{4}
\LabelsIn{1,2,3}{4}{5}
\LabelsIn{$\alpha$,$\beta$}{5}{1}
\LabelsOutside{A,B}{5}{1}
\LabelsOutside{M,N,O,P,Q}{2}{3}
\LabelsInside{x,y,z}{1}{2}
\LabelsInside{G,H,I}{3}{4}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Explanation

- The basic command is

  ```
  \DrawShape{<number of sides>}{<inner length>}{<outer length>}
  ```

  For example,

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawShape{3}{7cm}{10cm}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```

  Produces

  [image]

  Automatically, corners of this figure are numbered `1,...,<number of sides>`.
- To place labels in a side you use

  ```
  \LabelsIn{<list of labels>}{<start corner>}{<end corner>}
  ```

  So, for example,

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawShape{3}{7cm}{10cm}
  \LabelsIn{1,2,3,4}{1}{2}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```

  Produces

  [image]
- The commands `\LabelsInside` and `\LabelsOutside` have a similar syntax and are used to place labels outside a side or inside it. For example:

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawShape{3}{7cm}{10cm}
  \LabelsIn{1,2,3,4}{1}{2}
  \LabelsIn{$\alpha$,$\beta$}{2}{3}
  \LabelsIn{A,B,C,D}{3}{1}
  \LabelsInside{p,q,r,s}{3}{1}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```

  results in

  [image]

Comment: It works. I tried just using the new function you provided in my original code, gave leftinner not found . There seems to be some namespace clash. I could not change the words `bleft` and `bright` in your code; seem like high affinity to particular words.

Comment: @jayr I updated my answer with a new approach. In some hours I'll add the explanations on how to use the commands.

Comment: @jayr I have updated my answer again. Now it's much simpler. I'm adding a little explanation right now.

Comment: (+1) This would make a great library for CTAN.

Answer (score 5):

Requires some tweaking (e.g., with positioning), but most of the work is done:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\empty{}
\tikzset{pics/divided polygon/.style args={#1#2#3#4}{code={%
\def\N{#1}\def\R{#2}\def\r{#3}\def\Labels{#4}
\begin{scope}[rotate=270-180/\N-360/\N]
\path \foreach \i in {1,...,\N} { (360/\N*\i:\R) coordinate (n-\i-1) };
\path \foreach \i in {1,...,\N} { (360/\N*\i:{\R+\r/cos(180/\N)}) 
  coordinate (n-\i-2) };
\foreach \i in {1,2}
  \draw (n-1-\i) \foreach \j in {2,...,\N}{ -- (n-\j-\i) } -- cycle;
\foreach \l in {1,...,\N} \draw (n-\l-1) -- (n-\l-2);
\end{scope}
\foreach \labels [count=\i, evaluate={\j=int(mod(\i,\N)+1);}] in \Labels{
\foreach \a [count=\nlabels, remember=\nlabels] in \labels{}
\ifnum\nlabels>1
\foreach \k  in {2,...,\nlabels}
  \draw ($(n-\i-1)!{(\k-1)/\nlabels}!(n-\j-1)$) 
    coordinate (@) -- ($(n-\i-2)!(@)!(n-\j-2)$);
\fi
\foreach \l [count=\k] in \labels
\path 
  ($(n-\i-1)!{(\k-.5)/\nlabels}!(n-\j-1)$) 
    coordinate (side-\i-inner label-\k)
  ($(n-\i-2)!(side-\i-inner label-\k)!(n-\j-2)$) 
    coordinate (side-\i-outer label-\k)
  ($(side-\i-inner label-\k)!0.5!(side-\i-outer label-\k)$)
    coordinate (side-\i-label-\k);
\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{n-\i-1}{center}}%
  {\pgfpointanchor{n-\j-1}{center}}%
\pgfgetlastxy\px\py%
\pgfmathparse{Mod(atan2(\py/2,\px/2),360)}%
\let\sideangle=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{Mod(\pgfmathresult,180)-90}%
\let\textangle=\pgfmathresult%
\foreach \l [count=\k]  in \labels{
  \tikzset{get labels/.expand once=\l}
  \node [rotate=\textangle, text height=1em, text depth=.5em, 
    anchor=center, every main label/.try] 
    at (side-\i-label-\k) {\mainlabel};
  \node  [rotate=\textangle, text height=1em, text depth=.5em, 
    anchor={(\sideangle < 180) ? 270 : 90}, every outer label/.try] 
      at (side-\i-outer label-\k) {\outerlabel};
  \node  [rotate=\textangle, text height=1em, text depth=.5em, 
    anchor={(\sideangle >= 180) ? 270 : 90}, every inner label/.try]  
      at (side-\i-inner label-\k)  {\innerlabel};
}}}},
get labels/.style={.. get labels=#1///@},
.. get labels/.code args={#1/#2/#3/#4@}{%
  \def\mainlabel{#1}\def\outerlabel{#3}\def\innerlabel{#2}%
},
every outer label/.style={inner sep=0 },
every inner label/.style={inner sep=0 }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {divided polygon={3}{2}{0.5}%
  {{a/A/$\alpha$,b//$\beta$,c/C},{d//$\delta$,e//$\epsilon$},{f/F}}};
\pic at (8,0) {divided polygon={4}{2}{0.5}%
    {{a/A, b/B/$\beta$, c},{d,e},{f},{g,h,i,j}}};
\pic at (0,8) {divided polygon={5}{2}{1}%
  {{a/A,b/B,c},{d//$\delta$,e},{f/F},{g//$\gamma$,h,i,j/J},{k}}};
\pic at (8,8) {divided polygon={6}{3}{1}%
  {{a/A/$\alpha$,b,c},{d,e},{f},{g,h,i//$\iota$},{j/J,k/K/$\kappa$},{l}}};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant answer, as usual (you got my up-vote right after you posted it). I'm curious about those `@` characters in your code (if I recall correctly, before the last edit you had even `@@` and `@@@`). Could you please explain their role or direct me to some place where I can read about it?

Comment: This is elegant and compact code; @Gonazalo Medina's solution is more adaptable. I have different triangles and rectangles that have varying divisions and labels. Thanks! Will you be able to provide some comments to make it a little more understandable?

Comment: I'd like to second @GonzaloMedina's request.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Search for `\pgf@stop` in the code ;)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I used `@` (and `@@`, and `@@@`) as "temporary" coordinates: coordinates used in the construction of the path (so need to be named) but which don't really serve any other purpose (so don't need to be named sensibly). As percusse points out, I also used `@`as a delimiter in keys stuff.